# Fabric have a BUG on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-fabric

I use the method to upload my custom backtrace

```
[[Crashlytics sharedInstance] recordCustomExceptionName:@"test" reason:@"error" frameArray:myArray];
```

in "myArray" have two address 0x10005f35b and 0x10005f1b7

on my macbook, i use "dwarfdump" to parse 0x10005f35b and 0x10005f1b7 can get correct symbol.

but i upload 0x10005f35b and 0x10005f1b7 to fabric, fabric cannot symbol 0x10005f35b

fabric result :

```
0x10005f35b (Missing) 
0x10005f1b7 -[ViewController fabricStackTest:]
```

why fabric cannot parse address 0x10005f35b??

the same IPA file and same DSym file，i did upload DSym file to fabric

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. I see you already email our support team and they'll follow up there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem, it's my app bug, thank you

When you see "(Missing)" on Crashlytics UI, You can first check the memory offset is the same as fabric?

memory_offset = _dyld_get_image_vmaddr_slide(i)

> _dyld_get_image_vmaddr_slide() returns the virtural memory address slide amount of the image indexed by image_index. If image_index is out of range zero is returned.

memory_offset is different in every app launch.

> memory_address - memory_offset = file_address

file_address and .dSYM can corrent symbolicate a address.

my bug is i save memory_address to the file and next app launch, i pass to fabric SDK, next app launch the memory_offset is different, so fabric cannot symbolicate the address.

---

My Solution:
I save file_address to the file, and next app launch, i do addition,
file_address + memory_offset = now_address,
i pass now_address to SDK, can corrent symbolication